# Is it possible to link 2 public address to another one?

Tags: web3js, transactions, ether, wallets, wallet-transfer

i've seen this in exchanges wallets. so if u transfer some coins to the address which is use for deposits even after it change, it would still link to your wallet. so i want to make a gateway for my application. so its like 7 public ETH address would route all to a main wallet. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be possible with the basic transfer flow on Ethereum. Still, you may be able to achieve it in one of the following ways:

1. Use smart contracts instead of EOAs [custom contract logic]
   Custom contract with some **redirect** method. Users transfer to these contracts. Once in a while, when gas is cheap, you (the owner) can redirect these funds towards a treasury wallet. For ETH, I think you can also implement special handlers for the deposits, but not for [ERC20s](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/55427/71106).
2. Pre-approved wallets [custom contract logic]
   There's still the need for you to pay gas for "harvesting" but you could pre-approve a treasury contract to spend ERC20s from these 7 addresses. Once in a while, you'd redirect the assets into that contract, where you as the owner would be able to finally manage the assets.
3. Use a custom backend [pure web3]
   Use a custom backend that has access (private keys) to those wallets and once in a while run a script that collects funds.

By the way, this question has been asked before.
Check: [(1)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18387/how-to-monitor-all-your-addresses-and-send-payments-out-immediately-to-a-main-ad/18409#18409), [(2)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58055/how-do-exchanges-transfer-tokens-from-user-wallets) or [(3)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15726/how-can-i-read-any-token-units-received-in-a-smart-contract-ether-and-other-to/41051#41051) for more details and possible solutions.